# Is it ok to comment "working on that" to prevent other users from helping the OP out?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

I guess the title is quite self-explanatory but I'll dig deeper into that.

I can see questions sometimes that requires work to be answered at. So here is my thought: « *Is it OK to comment on the question to let others SO users that someone is already working on it?* ». This could discourage others SO users with lower reputation points to handle the question. I guess someone who's higher won't take this comment into consideration.

This can assure me the reputation gained from a possibly good answer.

Now here what I think: **It's not OK to do so** as it prevents the OP from getting the potential help from all SO users. And what if I cannot do the job? The OP might not getting any answer at all.

As you can see, I already have an opinion on it but I thought it was worth asking the question.

Comment: You post a proper answer or not an answer at all. *Working on that* will get a downvote from me as that is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank @MartijnPieters but I was talking about leaving a **comment** to let others know, not an *answer* :)

Comment: If your answer is a *good answer* and better than what can be posted quickly, then you'll get the up votes. There is no 'reserving a spot'.

Comment: A comment like that should be flagged as "not constructive".

Comment: Right, but a) I doubt anyone will be stopped from posting an answer, whatever reputation they have, and b) no, there is no need to reserve a spot. Don't do that; such comments will probably get flagged as not constructive or similar.

Comment: Thanks you people for commenting and letting me know of what could happen in such cases.

Comment: I thought about commenting something like “Working on it” on a question today. But my intention was to let the questioner know that _someone’s_ working on his question, that his question is basically taken care of. But it was _not_ to reserve any spot—that would be stupid in this community… would this still get flagged, though?

Comment: Why is this question getting so many downvotes? Is it really such a bad question? It seems like people are voting on the practice the question describes (that it is not right to make such comments) rather than the question itself. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, don't post such comments. You don't get to reserve a spot, nor would such a comment even work, very few people would actually see such a comment and go *oh, I'll just not post then*, regardless of reputation.

If your answer is actually helpful, it'll get voted up. Over time, if not immediately. But if someone else posted a helpful and correct answer *first*, then they were simply faster. You cannot and should not try and head that off. In the end, what matters is that the question is answered, and ideally it is answered in such a way it is useful to future visitors. *That* is what gets the reputation.