# Folks With Less Than 2K Suggesting Edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, reputation

I just noticed something interesting.

I was doing my community service (reviews), and ran through the various options.

A number of them are not yet within my bailiwick, as I haven't achieved a sufficient rep.

However, in "Suggested Edits," I noticed that 3 of the 6 "recent edits" had reps lower than 2K.

In fact, one of them had a rep of 1.

This seemed the case for only that category.

I'm curious as to why is this?

Comment: Looks like you never suggested an edit yourself :) If you're good with grammar and formatting, it's a nice thing to do, earns points and trains you for when you have editing privileges.

Comment: On downvotes: I strongly suspect you are getting "not researched" downvotes as first link when you search for "suggested edit" leads to SE blog post https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ describing what exactly such edits are and explaining why all such suggestions are from users with less than 2K rep...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any user can suggest an edit. These suggestions go to the "Suggested Edits" queue and need to either be approved (earning the suggester +2 rep) or rejected.

Once a user earns 2K reputation, he'll earn the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege and his edits to questions and answers would be applied immediately without review. Once a user earns 20K reputation, he'll earn the [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege, and his edits to tag wikis won't have to pend approval either.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for all the downvotes! I get the message. Won't be asking any more meta questions.

Comment: @MAGNAWS Please keep in mind that while voting on the main site judges the quality/usefulness of a post, voting on meta indicates agreement/disagreement. No reputation is lost for downvotes on meta. Obviously it isn't a perfect system as it scares people off (like you!) For more information please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @MAGNAWS: 7 downvotes is not that bad. We can see questions here that go [down](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299943/what-if-reputation-points-have-an-expiration-date) [to](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288882/is-it-ok-to-comment-working-on-that-to-prevent-other-users-from-helping-the-op) [much](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296896/are-rep-hounds-necessarily-bad-people) much more. This shouldn't prevent you from posting on meta though.

Comment: *Any user can suggest an edit.* - @MAGNAWS - you may also find it interesting to note that 'user' here means anyone visiting the site, not just registered users. Even folks that aren't logged in can suggest edits.

Comment: Wasn't aware that you don't have to be logged in to suggest an edit. Thanks @BSMP

Comment: @MAGNAWS Thanks to the meta-meta-effect, the vote count of your question has gone back up to -5.